# CM-14.1 compilation error on Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: kernel, 15.10, android, github

I'm attempting to rebuild **Cyanogenmod 14.1** with **Realtek drivers** support on **Ubuntu**. I have managed to download the entire CM source code as well proprietary specific files for my phone which is a **Motorola Nexus 6 (shamu)** as mentioned in this guide [Android CyanogenMod Kernel Building](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/android-cyanogenmod-kernel-building-monitor-mode-any-android-device-with-wireless-adapter-0162943/)

However, I'm facing problems with the final step of compiling the ROM. I run the following command:

```
brunch shamu
```

(*shamu being the codename for my device*)

then i get the following output.....

```
including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
build/core/envsetup.mk:89: *** Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm: Linux i686!.  Stop.
Device shamu not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from CyanogenMod Github (http://github.com/CyanogenMod).
Found repository: android_device_moto_shamu
Default revision: cm-14.1
Checking branch info
Checking if device/moto/shamu is fetched from android_device_moto_shamu
CyanogenMod/android_device_moto_shamu already fetched to device/moto/shamu
Syncing repository to retrieve project.
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_device_moto_shamu
Fetching projects: 100% (1/1), done.  

Repository synced!
Looking for dependencies in device/moto/shamu
Done
build/core/envsetup.mk:89: *** Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm: Linux i686!.  Stop.
build/core/envsetup.mk:89: *** Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm: Linux i686!.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_shamu'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

No such item in brunch menu. Try 'breakfast'
```

The command `breakfast` shows the same error, and I have checked I have the correct repo mainfest.

---

what could the following error mean?

```
build/core/envsetup.mk:89: *** Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm: Linux i686!.  Stop.
```

Comment: already tried breakfast same exact error

Comment: yes i have the right repo manifest

Comment: Now that the info is added lets clear the comment section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it fixed by downloading accurately modified versions of the **makefiles** needed to compile the ROM from this website [code.metager.de](http://code.metager.de)